# How can i find the incidences of my attributes in Weka?

Tags: r, weka

I have diagnoses, ages and their quantities. 
For example,

[image]

I have more than 50+ with duplicate diagnoses. I want to see the incidence of this age+quatity relation in new column. How can i do that ?

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example? Also, please do not post images as input as it is difficult to copy from it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Well i try to show the incidence of Age and Quantity for diagnoses.

Comment: Do you just need `table(df$Diagnose)`?

Comment: I want to see another column that shows the incidence like weighted average. Numerical output column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is stored in a dataframe called `df`, try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(diagnosis, age, quatity) %>% summarise(n())
```

This will give you a `data.frame` with the number of occurrences for each diagnosis at a given age and for a given "quatity". Please make sure the latter is spelled correctly.

For instance, using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, vs, carb) %>% summarise(n())
Source: local data frame [11 x 4]
Groups: cyl, vs [?]

     cyl    vs  carb `n()`
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1      4     0     2     1
2      4     1     1     5
3      4     1     2     5
4      6     0     4     2
5      6     0     6     1
6      6     1     1     2
7      6     1     4     2
8      8     0     2     4
9      8     0     3     3
10     8     0     4     6
11     8     0     8     1
```

Here, the first line tells you that there is only one car with `cyl = 4, vs = 0, carb = 2`, and there are 5 cars with `(cyl, vs, carb) = (4, 1, 1)`. If you want the column added to the old `data.frame`, use `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

These kind of operations are often referred to as `split-apply-combine`. It is worthwhile reading up on them.

---

Just for reference: this question used to be "How can i find the incidences of my attributes in R or Weka?" It has been changed to Weka only after I have supplied the answer for R.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance i can get the same result in Weka ?

Comment: Also, how can i eliminate the duplicate diagnoses ?

Comment: I don't know anything about `Weka`, but I would be surprised if you could not achieve the same. If you use `summarise` as described above, there will be no duplicates in the output.

Comment: Which Weka interface do you want to use - Explorer, Experimenter, Knowledge Flow, CLI or Java API?

Comment: Any interface that solve my problem. I need to see which diagnose has the most quantity in ages. For example Cancer is seen in age 50 with max quantity. Then a table like descending.